# How to control the exact appearance of GUI apps in Docker

Tags: docker, x-windows

I'm using [Sikuli](http://sikulix.com) in order to run automated tests in web servers.

It compares the screen rendered by the browser with pre-captured screenshots, and emulates clicks and user input.

The problem I'm having, is that a simple update of the system can change the appearence of fonts.

Solution, I've tried is to run it in a Docker container, a more controlled environent.

I'm having 2 environments:

1. One that uses Xvfb (X Window virtual frame buffer) in order to run unattended tests
2. One that uses the Sikuli GUI in order to write new tests or modify existing ones.

With case 1) I don't have problems having a uniform and repeatable appearnace.

In order to run the editor, I've managed to run the Docker container by connecting it with the host X-windows server.

The problem is that e.g. font and appearance changes.

How can I deal with case 2) ?

Some ideas:

- Installing a VNC server or something similar in my Docker image.  I think the GUI will be slower and clumsier.  [Related info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented a VNC server in my docker image, by embedding novnc, and the rendering of GUI apps is predictable.